# How do I authenticate with Azure in order to run a data factory pipeline test with python behave?

Tags: python, azure-data-factory, python-behave

I have a pipeline on Azure Data Factory that I want to write a test for using python behave. For now I just want to run a test locally. The following command won't run just now as I haven't authenticated in any way.

```
get_client_from_cli_profile(DataFactoryManagementClient)
```

The error message says I need to run 'az login' to setup account.

```
knack.util.CLIError: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
```

Could somebody give an example of how I do this?

Feature

```
Feature: Run pipeline
    Scenario: Get pipeline
        Given we get the pipeline
```

Step

```
@given('we get the pipeline')
def get_pipeline(context):
    pipeline_name = "xxx"
    resource_group = "yyy"
    data_factory = "zzz"
    parameters={}
    pipeline = get_datafactory_pipeline(pipeline_name, resource_group, data_factory, parameters)
```

Code to get pipeline

```
from azure.common.client_factory import get_client_from_cli_profile
from azure.mgmt.datafactory import DataFactoryManagementClient

def get_datafactory_pipeline(pipeline_name, resource_group, data_factory, parameters):
    return get_client_from_cli_profile(DataFactoryManagementClient().pipelines.create_run(
        resource_group_name = resource_group,
        factory_name = data_factory,
        pipeline_name = pipeline_name,
        parameters = parameters)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two way:

1.install Azure CLI and then `az login` access to Azure.(download link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli)

[image]

2.no need to install Azure CLI but change your code like this:

```
def get_datafactory_pipeline(subscription_id,credentials,pipeline_name, resource_group, data_factory, parameters):
    return DataFactoryManagementClient(credentials,subscription_id).pipelines.create_run(
        resource_group_name=resource_group,
        factory_name=data_factory,
        pipeline_name=pipeline_name,
        parameters=parameters)
```

and your step like this:

```
@given('we get the pipeline')
def get_pipeline(context):
    subscription_id = '<Specify your Azure Subscription ID>'
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id='<Active Directory application/client ID>', secret='<client secret>', tenant='<Active Directory tenant ID>')
    pipeline_name = "xxx"
    resource_group = "yyy"
    data_factory = "zzz"
    parameters={}
    pipeline = get_datafactory_pipeline(subscription_id,credentials,pipeline_name, resource_group, data_factory, parameters)
```